# Type Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Tags: java, android, google-maps, syntax, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making a simple map application but on running it, errors are displayed which i   don't understand....

my project min SDK is android 2.2(Froyo) API 8 , target SDK is android   4.4(kitkat) API 19 and app is compiled with Google API 2 rev 8.....

I really don't know what should be the combinations of min, target and compiled apis in   order to make my app run ....help me out with the proper combination.

following is my manifest file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.margallahillhikedroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>"
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.margallahillhikedroid.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

// following is main java source

// package com.example.margallahillhikedroid;

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
MapView map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mymap);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

following is main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
      android:id="@+id/mymap"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:apiKey="AIzaSyBcTxeirTSzthVlMal5JDDC-SK-Mw7s_CE"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

on running the app following errors in console section displayed;

```
[2014-04-14 07:37:14 - MargallahillHikedroid] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-04-14 07:37:14 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex:     java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2014-04-14 07:37:14 - MargallahillHikedroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed:    Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack   trace.
```

in the problem section following error is displayed

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace. MargallahillHikedroid       Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

I am making a map application but on running it above mentioned errors are displayed in the problem section as well as the console section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to implement Google Maps API V1, probably using the Google Maps API V2 key. And That you can't do.

So what you should do is make the following changes in your code:

**1.** Remove: `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>"`
from your manifest file, this a V1 permission.

**2.** If you want to support V8 API then you have to remove the implementation of you activity to `MapActivity` and change it to `FragmentActivity`. For supporting fragment on older systems.

**3.** Change you xml layout file from:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
  android:id="@+id/mymap"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:apiKey="AIzaSyBcTxeirTSzthVlMal5JDDC-SK-Mw7s_CE"/>
```

To this:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**4.** Finally you have to add some staff in your manifest file:

Add those permissions:

```
<permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>
```

change your.application.package to your actual application package name.

And add those:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="Your Google Maps API V2 Key" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

under the `application` hive.

You can also use this guide that I wrote on this topic to help you out:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

and go over the steps of producing the api key and make sure you haven't missed any thing:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Comment: I had some problems with my blog's server, should be good to go now :)

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes appen with Eclipse. You just have to close Eclipse, relaunch it, clean your project, refresh it, and retry... It should do the trick... ;)

Comment: man come on what you suggested have already given it a shot but that does not work!!!! i need a proper answer and the error solution of my project...

Comment: That's the way I handle this problem, when it happen... And it works for me... Then, maybe it doesn't work for you and someone has another answer... Good luck. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The min sdk forvmap v2 is 11 please change to that.And try

Comment: HOW TO CHANGE IT NOW?procedure plz

Comment: U can find declaration of min sdk in manifest.xml file there u can change the min sdk version

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement Google Map V2. May be following line causing the problem in the manifest uses-library `android:name="com.google.android.maps"`

Comment: i am using Google Map v2

Comment: could you please tell me what is wrong with the combinations of apis?like if there is error in the min sdk or target sdk or compile with api /version

Comment: tell me what change should i made in the mentioned line of manifest

Comment: No you are not see this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: i have checked the link but tell me how you found that i am not using Google Map api V2?

Comment: You have implemented Map V1 Change it to Map V2